# Problema com consulta sql na minha aplicação ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, sql

Estou com problema na hora que preciso consultar informações no banco de dados através do meu comando sql em minha aplicação Asp.Net Core. Já fiz pesquisa aqui no StackOverFlow e não achei.

Erro: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'É necessário declarar a variável escalar "@ClienteId".'`

Método responsável por realizar essa consulta:

```
 public Cliente ConsultarCliente(long? id)
    {

        Cliente item;
        DAL acessarBanco = new DAL(); // Instanciando objeto acessar banco para realizar a conexão de dados.
        string sqlConsulta = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Estudo.Clientes WHERE ClienteId = @ClienteId");

        //string sqlConsulta = $"Select ClienteId, Nome, CpfCnpj, Email, Senha From Estudo.Clientes Where ClienteId ='{ClienteId}' order by Nome asc"; //  variavel sqlConsulta para trazer todas os registros da tabela Clientes.
        DataTable dt = acessarBanco.RetDataTable(sqlConsulta);



        item = new Cliente
        {
            ClienteId = dt.Rows[0]["ClienteId"].ToString(),
            Nome = dt.Rows[0]["Nome"].ToString(),
            CpfCnpj = dt.Rows[0]["CpfCnpj"].ToString(),
            Email = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString(),
            Senha = dt.Rows[0]["Senha"].ToString()
        };

        return item;
    }
```

Classe DAL com minha conexão:

```
 public DAL()

    {
        Conexao = new SqlConnection(StringConexao);
        Conexao.Open();
    }

    public DataTable RetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand Executar = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexao);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Executar);
        da.Fill(data);
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na consulta está a ser indicada a variavel @ClienteId mas esta não está a ser preenchida.
Normalmente quando se utiliza uma variavel, esta é preenchida com um valor para aplicar de forma dinamica um filtro.
Ex: fazer replace do texto "@ClienteId" pelo codigo de um cliente ou ID.

Qual o objectivo do filtro where na consulta SQL?

Comment: Antonio, boa noite.
Estou tentando chamar um registro pelo parametro id, ao identificar o id 5 por exemplo ele me traga com os campos preenchido para que eu possa realizar essa alteração..

Comment: deu certo aqui obrigado.